# python, conda: ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'd:\\anaconda3\\envs\\python39\\scripts\\pip.exe'

Tags: python, pip, conda

I have tried to install `requirements.txt` using `pip install -r requirements.txt`. I always get this error:

```
  Using cached ansicon-1.89.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (63 kB)
Installing collected packages: ansicon, wcwidth, six, jinxed, urllib3, readchar, python-editor, python-dateutil, jmespath, idna, chardet, certifi, blessed, requests, pyyaml, pip, mypy-extensions, inquirer, click, botocore, attrs, rollbar, redis, chalice
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 21.3.1
    Uninstalling pip-21.3.1:
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'd:\\anaconda3\\envs\\python39\\scripts\\pip.exe'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

> Note that I am using windows 10 as OS.

I find out that the process of installation **"removes my pip script"** from Scripts, that is why I run `pip install -r requirements.txt --user` I got

```
Cannot open D:\anaconda3\envs\python39\Scripts\pip-script.py
```

I have also tried to upgrade pip but could not

```
Cannot open D:\anaconda3\envs\python39\Scripts\pip-script.py
```

For those who may say try to install pip via conda first I am getting:

```
$ conda install pip
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done


==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 4.10.1
  latest version: 4.10.3

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda     



# All requested packages already installed.
```

I have run the command as administrator, I have tried many versions of python within `conda`. I have also installed python globally (once I restart my system the global python folder vanish). I have also tried to install the requirements file with conda but it does not find the `chalice` and `rollbar` in conda or conda forge channel.

This is my `requirements.txt`

```
chalice==1.23.0
requests==2.25.1
rollbar==0.15.2
redis==3.5.3
```

How could I fix this?

Comment: Seems like OS cannot access the pip file. Can you try pip3? I mean, "pip3 install ..."

Comment: Same error alwyas

Comment: Virtual environment is usually recommended so if it fits your use case you could do that.

Comment: python venv u mean I have tried that also always same result.

Comment: try conda install pip first

Comment: Check the updates all those solutions does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the missing script due to installation, use this: `python -m ensurepip --default-pip`  For more, you can check [this](https://programmerah.com/solved-pycharm-use-pip-error-script-file-danaconda3envspytorchscriptspip-script-py-is-not-present-37598/)
You can also check this issue on GitHub [here](https://github.com/DamnWidget/anaconda/issues/762)

### What is ensurepip and when to use it?

`ensurepip` is a package that supports bootstrapping for `pip`. It is used when for some reason installing pip was skipped. From the doc:

> In most cases, end users of Python shouldn’t need to invoke this module directly (as pip should be bootstrapped by default), but it may be needed if installing pip was skipped when installing Python (or when creating a virtual environment) or after explicitly uninstalling pip.

check out [ensurepip doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ensurepip.html)

Comment: Thank you so much you saved my life but I did not get exactly what the command does?